# Loop in the same table on ids found with an id

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a simple table:

| Main_ID | Sub_ID1 | Sub_ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| ID2 | ID4 | ID5 |
| ID3 | ID7 | ID12 |

Where a product in Main_ID is made with products in Sub_ID1 and Sub_ID2.

I would like, for a given id, have  all the products (sub_ids) necessary for its realisation.

For example: For the id ID1, I will have ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID7, ID12.
(ID1 is made with ID2 and ID3, but ID2 is made with ID4 and ID5, and ID3 is made with ID7 and ID12, etc.)

I've tried some left join, but I miss something I guess.

```
SELECT t1.Main_ID
FROM my_table t1
INNER JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.Sub_ID1  t1.Main_ID OR t2.Sub_ID2  t1.Main_ID
WHERE t1.Main_ID LIKE 'ID1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a reliable way using a recursive query.

Although you need to do a preprocessing step first: "*Sub_ID1*" and "*Sub_ID2*" should be found within one single Sub_ID column, using the `UNION ALL` operator. We're calling the output of this step as "crafted table".

Then you can apply recursion defining these two steps:

- base step, select the "*main_id*" record you want to inspect
- recursive step, joining base-step table with the crafted table on matching <"*Main_ID*", "*SubID*">

```
WITH RECURSIVE one_subid AS (
    SELECT Main_ID, Sub_ID1 AS Sub_ID FROM tab
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Main_ID, Sub_ID2 AS Sub_ID FROM tab
), cte_rec AS (
    SELECT Main_ID, Sub_ID FROM one_subid WHERE Main_ID = 'ID1'
    
    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT t2.Sub_ID, t1.Sub_ID
    FROM       one_subid t1
    INNER JOIN cte_rec   t2 ON t1.Main_ID = t2.Sub_ID  
)
SELECT Sub_ID FROM cte_rec
```

Output for 'Main_ID = ID1':

| sub_id |
| --- |
| ID2 |
| ID3 |
| ID4 |
| ID7 |
| ID5 |
| ID12 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k1sbqyVkuLi8kyY1LhkCQD/3).

Comment: Thank you for you answer !

But what if I want that for one ID, and not al the IDS in my table ?

Comment: Hum, doesn't seem to work? When I verify, it miss one value.

Comment: You are forced to carry out all the recursion, then filter in the last select. Updated the answer accordingly with `WHERE Main_ID = <some_id>`. If you want to filter on more than one id, you use `WHERE Main_ID IN (<id1>, <id2>, ...)`

Comment: (I also tried with the demo, just gave me ID_2 and ID_3) where I would like ID_2, ID3 , ID4, ID5, ID7, ID12

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k1sbqyVkuLi8kyY1LhkCQD/2

Comment: Great ! I'll try in my db and tell you ;) A big thank you !

Comment: I've added another second simplified solution if you need to query only one element at a time.

Comment: So perfect ! A big Thank you :) Now I juste need to incorporate a left join with another table in order to get a new value and it's ok ! Thank you for all !